# How to pass custom props to drawer screens in React Navigation 5?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

Here's my Drawer Navigation config:

```js
  return (
    <NavigationContainer theme={navigationTheme}>
      <Drawer.Navigator
        drawerContent={(props) => (
          <DrawerContent {...props} />
        )}
      >
        <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="About" component={AboutScreen} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
```

and in my `DrawerContent` component:

```js
export default function DrawerContent({ state, navigation, ...props }) {
  return (
    <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
        <Drawer.Section>
          {state.routes.map((route) => (
            <DrawerItem
              key={route.key}
              label={route.name}
              onPress={() => navigation.navigate(route.name)}
            />
          ))}
        </Drawer.Section>
      </View>
    </DrawerContentScrollView>
  );
}
```

I want to add an `icon` prop to my `DrawerItem` component inside the `DrawerContent` component. I tried doing this:

```js
<Drawer.Screen name="Home" icon="home" component={HomeScreen} />
```

and in my `DrawerContent`

```js
{state.routes.map((route) => (
    <DrawerItem
        key={route.key}
        icon={({ color, size }) => (
        <MaterialCommunityIcons name="home" icon={route.icon} color={color} size={size} />
        )}
        label={route.name}
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate(route.name)}
    />
))}
```

But the `route.icon` property is `undefined`. Any idea on this?

Answer (score 3):

Fixed it using [options prop on Screen](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/screen-options).

In my Drawer Navigator:

```js
<Drawer.Navigator>
  <Drawer.Screen
    name="Home"
    component={HomeScreen}
    options={{ icon: 'home' }}
  />
</Drawer.Navigator>
```

and to access it in the custom `DrawerContent` component:

```js
export default function DrawerContent({ state, navigation, ...props }) {

    const getIcon = (key) => props.descriptors[key].options.icon;

    return (
        <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
            <Drawer.Section>
            {state.routes.map((route) => (
                <DrawerItem
                key={route.key}
                label={route.name}
                icon={({ color, size }) => (
                    <MaterialCommunityIcons
                        name={getIcon(route.key)}
                        color={color}
                        size={size}
                    />
                )}
                onPress={() => navigation.navigate(route.name)}
                />
            ))}
            </Drawer.Section>
        </View>
        </DrawerContentScrollView>
    );
}
```